# Given $2^x+3^x=4$, find all non-trivial rational $a, b, c$ such that $a^x+b^x=c$, or prove that none exist.

Tags: exponentiation, rational-numbers

> Given $2^x+3^x=4$, find all non-trivial rational $a, b, c$ such that $a^x+b^x=c$, or prove that none exist.

(Trivial solutions include those with $a$ and $b$ as $0$ or $1$, for example $a=b=c=0$; or $a=b=1, c=2$, etc. The other trivial solution is $a=2, b=3, c=4$.)

I have not found any such $a, b, c$. Are there any? I have tried setting $a=\frac{p}{q}$ etc., as well as raising both sides of $2^x+3^x=4$ to positive integer powers, to no avail.

(This question was inspired by [How to find the solution to $4^x+9^x=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504173/how-to-find-the-solution-to-4x-9x-4).)

Comment: $x\approx 0.76$

Comment: @abcdefu My question does not require us to find or approximate the value of $x$.

Comment: Do you count $4^x+3^x=91$ as trivial$?$

Comment: @abcdefu We are given that $2^x+3^x=4$, so $x<1$, so $4^x+3^x$ does not equal $91$.

Comment: The answer is probably no solutions unless there is some exceptional identity that creates them.